# Moved ASP servers and now my pages can't send mails getting the "Failure sending mail" error

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, mail-server

This used to work on the old server and I got the files backed up and got the system running on the new server. Databases are all intact and connected, files are all there but whenever a user wants to register, they get the "Failure sending mail" error.

This is the line in the registeration file that handles the activation mail sending:

```
                    MailClass.MailGonder("info@mysite.com", TxtEMail.Text, "Aktivasyon Kodu", body, "info@mysite.com", "mypasswordishere", "mail.mysite.com", 587);
```

And this is the Mail_Class.cs file which I'm pretty sure handles the whole mail thing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace Sngl
{
public class MailClass
{
    public MailClass() { }

    public static void MailGonder(string kimden, string kime, string title, string body, string senderEmail, string senderPassword, string smtpServer, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(kimden, kime, title, body);
            MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            MyMailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new
            System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpServer, port);
            mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
            mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);

            PropertyClass.Result = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PropertyClass.Result = false;
            PropertyClass.Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? This used to work on the old server but the guy who set it up for me there doesn't reply to my emails or calls. I've tried for hours trying to get this up and running but nothing works. I tried using the internal subdomain of hosting as mail server, tried using ip and still it's the same result. double checked everything, the email address is there and the password is the same as the one in the file.

What can I do to know what's wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the relevance to classic asp?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first ASP site and I didn't even make it myself. I'm not even an ASP newbie, beyond newbie to be honest. I had this site developed for me and when they gave me the files and removed it off their own servers it's now showing problems with the mail server. no idea whatsoever why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the mail server isn't performing some authentication/security based on source IP?

Can you telnet to the mail server from the web server? e.g. telnet mailserverip port

Comment: I saw somebody else performing that test and did it, it fails to connect when I do that. 
The mailserver does seem to have a more complicated authentication but I can't seem to figure it out as I'm new to ASP (I didn't even make this site, just trying to get it working on my new server).

This is the page from my new hosting, but I can't figure out anything:

http://manage.hostingfest.com/whmcs/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=42

Comment: You may need to contact the mail server admin and get them to assist you in configuring mail from your new server

Comment: I contacted them and they said I should use port 26 but that still didn't work. Still your answer was the most helpful.