# ASP Mail feature not working after moving to a new server

Tags: asp.net, forms, email, mail-server

This used to work on the old server and I got the files backed up and got the system running on the new server. Databases are all intact and connected, files are all there but whenever a user wants to register, they get the "Failure sending mail" error.

This is the line in the registeration file that handles the activation mail sending:

```
                MailClass.MailGonder("info@mysite.com", TxtEMail.Text, "Aktivasyon Kodu", body, "info@mysite.com", "mypasswordishere", "mail.mysite.com", 587);
```

And this is the Mail_Class.cs file which I'm pretty sure handles the whole mail thing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace Sngl
{
public class MailClass
{
public MailClass() { }

public static void MailGonder(string kimden, string kime, string title, string body, string senderEmail, string senderPassword, string smtpServer, int port)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(kimden, kime, title, body);
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        MyMailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpServer, port);
        mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
        mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);

        PropertyClass.Result = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PropertyClass.Result = false;
        PropertyClass.Message = ex.Message;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: The registration goes through but the "Failure sending mail" error pops up and no activation email is sent.

Comment: Is 'Failure sending mail' the actual exception that gets caught? Have you tried stepping through with the debugger to see if there's more information about the exception?

Comment: I'm familiar with PHP but this is my first ASP site. How do I do that?

Comment: checked with the hosting site, the mail server and port are supposedly correct. but is there a way to test this?

Comment: Are you sure the email/password are still correct for authenticating at that host's mail server?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were doing this on a remote host. Try using the following code inside your catch to see if there's more info: PropertyClass.Message = ex.Message + (ex.InnerException != null)?' : ' + ex.InnerException.Message : "";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moved ASP servers and now my pages can't send mails getting the "Failure sending mail" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694021/moved-asp-servers-and-now-my-pages-cant-send-mails-getting-the-failure-sending)

Comment: You should delete this question and stick to the one you have already created that is exactly the same.

Comment: Is the email server configured to accept anonymous SMTP?  Does it need to be configured with a list of acceptable IP addresses?

Comment: Contacted the mail server admins, the authentication is working like it should BUT they said I should change the port from 567 to 26. Which by the way didn't make any difference, still the Failure sending mail error. I do believe their servers have a problem though. Waiting on an update from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything suggested, I'm pretty sure the problem is with the server as the same settings worked on the old server. I rechecked everything several times and still nothing. Waiting on an answer from the webhost support.